# Troubleshooting source of heavy resource-usage on a server 2008 running multiple sites

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, system-administration

I am running about 10 asp.net websites on a hosted virtual server.
The server runs Server 2008 - each website is backed by its own database running on SQL server 2008 on the same box.

Lately the box has seemed really slow. The only kind of discovery i could think of doing was looking in the task manager, where i can see w3wp and sqlserver.exe jumping to 40% cpu usage every 5-10 seconds.

What are the steps i can take to determine which of my websites is taking these resources and or what database is getting hit the most? I have of course ssms installed on the machine as well.

As you can tell, my sysadmin skills are very very limited - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @batman_man - welcome to stackoverflow. The site is for programming questions and answers, and this does not count as one. It will probably get migrated to ServerFault.com which is the sysadmin question and answer sister site.

Comment: I have now posted it on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be better asked at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Yes. Apologies for that, i have now posted it on serverfault instead.

Comment: anytime batman_man, I just found out about that site not long ago myself :)